# How to select Min and Max price from category base on regular or promo price

Tags: mysql

I like to select MIN and MAX price from category but if products have promo price should select promo price is not should select regular price

table look like this

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`name` varchar(155) NOT NULL,
`category_id` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
`cost` decimal(65,2) NOT NULL,
`promo_cost` decimal(62,2) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

This query work only if in category all products have promo price or do not have .

How to make it work for category where are mixed products with promo and without promo ?

```
SELECT 
 CASE 
  WHEN promo_cost != 0 
  THEN MAX(promo_cost) 
  ELSE MAX(cost) END as max_price 
FROM products WHERE category_id = $category_id
```

for example if i have in category:

product 1: cost 50.00, promo_cost 30.00

product 2: cost 60.00, promo_cost 40.00

product 3: cost 20.00, promo_cost 0.00

max should be 40 and min should be 20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is your variant

```
select min(tmpPrice) as min_price,max(tmpPrice) as max_price from
    (
        SELECT CASE WHEN promo_cost != 0 THEN promo_cost ELSE cost END as tmpPrice
            FROM products WHERE category_id = $category_id
    ) a
```

Comment: this look find let me test

Answer (score 0):

Based on your expected output, I think you want:

```sql
SELECT MIN(cost) AS min_cost, MAX(promo_cost) AS max_cost
FROM products
WHERE category_id = ?;
```

That is, the minimum cost is the smallest `cost`, and the maximum cost is the largest `promo_cost`.

Comment: minimum cost can also be promo_cost , in this case query wont work if product 3 have promo_cost of 10